# Applying conditional counts (with reset) to the grouped data in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, group-by, reset

I have a data frame that is grouped by **Calendar Date** and **ID**. I need to populate the **Expected Output** based on the **Booked**: Within each group, if **Booked** is equal to 1 then set the **output** to 0, otherwise count the not-booked days. In other words, I'm trying to find all the consecutive available days (not booked days) within a group. Any ideas on how to do this?

Grouped by **Calendar Date** and **ID** and find the **Expected Output** based on **Booked**.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vJDA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUlXZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical "Gaps and Islands problem". You can solve it like this:

```py
from datetime import date

from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DateType

SampleData = [
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 1, date(2022, 1, 1), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 1, date(2022, 1, 2), 1),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 1, date(2022, 1, 3), 1),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 1, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 2, date(2022, 1, 1), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 2, date(2022, 1, 2), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 2, date(2022, 1, 3), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 1), 2, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 2), 1, date(2022, 1, 2), 1),
  (date(2022, 1, 2), 1, date(2022, 1, 3), 1),
  (date(2022, 1, 2), 1, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 2), 2, date(2022, 1, 2), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 2), 2, date(2022, 1, 3), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 2), 2, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 3), 1, date(2022, 1, 3), 1),
  (date(2022, 1, 3), 1, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 3), 2, date(2022, 1, 3), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 3), 2, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 4), 1, date(2022, 1, 4), 0),
  (date(2022, 1, 4), 2, date(2022, 1, 4), 0)
]

ColumnSchema = StructType([
  StructField("CalendarDate", DateType()),
  StructField("ID", IntegerType()),
  StructField("Date2", DateType()),
  StructField("Booked", IntegerType()),
])

dfSampleData = spark.createDataFrame(SampleData, schema=ColumnSchema)

dfSampleDataWithRowNumbers = dfSampleData.selectExpr(
  "*",
  "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarDate, ID ORDER BY Date2) AS rn1",
  "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarDate, ID, Booked ORDER BY Date2) AS rn2"
).selectExpr(
  "*",
  "rn1 - rn2 AS GapsAndIslandsGroupNo"
).selectExpr(
  "*",
  "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CalendarDate, ID, GapsAndIslandsGroupNo ORDER BY Date2) AS ExpectedOutputRaw"
).selectExpr(
  "*",
  "CASE Booked WHEN 0 THEN ExpectedOutputRaw ELSE 0 END AS `Expected Output`"
).orderBy("CalendarDate", "ID", "Date2")

dfSampleDataWithRowNumbers.show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+---+----------+------+---+---+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|CalendarDate| ID|     Date2|Booked|rn1|rn2|GapsAndIslandsGroupNo|ExpectedOutputRaw|Expected Output|
+------------+---+----------+------+---+---+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
|  2022-01-01|  1|2022-01-01|     0|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-01|  1|2022-01-02|     1|  2|  1|                    1|                1|              0|
|  2022-01-01|  1|2022-01-03|     1|  3|  2|                    1|                2|              0|
|  2022-01-01|  1|2022-01-04|     0|  4|  2|                    2|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-01|  2|2022-01-01|     0|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-01|  2|2022-01-02|     0|  2|  2|                    0|                2|              2|
|  2022-01-01|  2|2022-01-03|     0|  3|  3|                    0|                3|              3|
|  2022-01-01|  2|2022-01-04|     0|  4|  4|                    0|                4|              4|
|  2022-01-02|  1|2022-01-02|     1|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              0|
|  2022-01-02|  1|2022-01-03|     1|  2|  2|                    0|                2|              0|
|  2022-01-02|  1|2022-01-04|     0|  3|  1|                    2|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-02|  2|2022-01-02|     0|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-02|  2|2022-01-03|     0|  2|  2|                    0|                2|              2|
|  2022-01-02|  2|2022-01-04|     0|  3|  3|                    0|                3|              3|
|  2022-01-03|  1|2022-01-03|     1|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              0|
|  2022-01-03|  1|2022-01-04|     0|  2|  1|                    1|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-03|  2|2022-01-03|     0|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-03|  2|2022-01-04|     0|  2|  2|                    0|                2|              2|
|  2022-01-04|  1|2022-01-04|     0|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              1|
|  2022-01-04|  2|2022-01-04|     0|  1|  1|                    0|                1|              1|
+------------+---+----------+------+---+---+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```